# Conversion failed when converting varchar value 'N' to data type smallint

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm just inserting some data from one table into another but I'm facing an error:

> Conversion failed when converting varchar value 'N' to data type smallint.

It is because one of the column where I'm inserting is of `smallint` data type but the data is coming as 'N' so it is throwing an error.

```
Insert into target
(
ID
) 
select
id
from source
```

Data type of `id` from source is of `varchar(10)` and data type of ID from target is of `smallint`.

Can anyone suggest any answers? I tried with cast function but it is not working.

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server have TRY_CAST()?

Comment: What kind of `smallint`value you expect the `'N'` to turn into?

Comment: It should be insert as it is into target table

Comment: What do you want to do with the 'N'? You can't insert that into an `int` column. You need to provide some sample data and explain how it should be handled.

Comment: Why do you want to insert an 'N' into an smallint column? I'd say you need to cleanse your data.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can't convert a VARCHAR(10) with a value of 'N' into a SMALLINT.

You need to decide what value, if any, to insert into the target table where the source value of `[id]` contains characters other than 0-9 or falls outside the range of a SMALLINT.

If you decide to null the value, you can use a `TRY_CAST()` function...

```sql
INSERT  INTO target ( [ID] )
SELECT  TRY_CAST ( [id] AS SMALLINT )
FROM    source ;
```

This will insert a `NULL`, in the event the source value of `[id]` contains characters other than 0-9 or converts to an integer outside of the range of a SMALLINT.

If you decide, instead, to insert a pre-determined number (say, 0) on this condition, you can combine a `TRY_CAST()` with a `COALESCE()` functions...

```sql
INSERT  INTO target ( [ID] )
SELECT  COALESCE ( TRY_CAST ( [id] AS SMALLINT ), 0 )
FROM    source ;
```

This will insert a `0`, in the event the source value of `[id]` contains characters other than 0-9 or converts to an integer outside of the range of a SMALLINT.